# GWT conflict between form validation and SuggestBox selection

Tags: java, gwt, widget

I have an issue with GWT SuggestBox widget.

I have a handler on every field of the form to submit it with enter key.
However I'd like to fill suggest box with enter key too.

Thus I'm trying to find a proper way to :
1. when I choose an item in suggest box (suggestion menu shown) and press enter, select this item
2. when suggestion menu is not show validate form

Any idea

Answer (score 1):

When you look at `SuggestBox` constructors, you will find [this](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/SuggestBox.html#SuggestBox-com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.SuggestOracle-com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.ValueBoxBase-com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.SuggestBox.SuggestionDisplay-):

```
public SuggestBox(SuggestOracle oracle,
                  ValueBoxBase<java.lang.String> box,
                  SuggestBox.SuggestionDisplay suggestDisplay)
```

> oracle - supplies suggestions based upon the current contents of the text widget
>
> box - the text widget
>
> suggestDisplay - the class used to display suggestions

`SuggestionDisplay` is what you need to check if `isSuggestionListShowing()`.

---

Example code:

```
@UiField
FormPanel uiFormPanel;
@UiField
TextBox uiTextBox;
@UiField(provided = true)
SuggestBox uiSuggestBox;

public SubmitTest() {

    // provided fields
    MultiWordSuggestOracle oracle = new MultiWordSuggestOracle();
    oracle.add("Cat");
    oracle.add("Dog");
    oracle.add("Horse");
    oracle.add("Canary");

    TextBox box = new TextBox();
    final DefaultSuggestionDisplay suggestDisplay = new DefaultSuggestionDisplay();

    uiSuggestBox = new SuggestBox(oracle, box, suggestDisplay);

    initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));

    uiFormPanel.addSubmitHandler(new SubmitHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSubmit(SubmitEvent event) {
            event.cancel();
            Window.alert("Submit!");
        }
    });

    uiTextBox.addKeyDownHandler(new KeyDownHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onKeyDown(KeyDownEvent event) {
            if(event.getNativeKeyCode() == KeyCodes.KEY_ENTER)
                uiFormPanel.submit();
        }
    });

    uiSuggestBox.addKeyDownHandler(new KeyDownHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onKeyDown(KeyDownEvent event) {
            if(event.getNativeKeyCode() == KeyCodes.KEY_ENTER)
                if(!suggestDisplay.isSuggestionListShowing())
                    uiFormPanel.submit();
        }
    });
}
```

UiBinder:

```
<g:FormPanel ui:field="uiFormPanel">
    <g:HTMLPanel>
        <g:TextBox ui:field="uiTextBox" />
        <g:SuggestBox ui:field="uiSuggestBox" />
    </g:HTMLPanel>
</g:FormPanel>
```

Comment: Worked well, thanks. Just a thing : isSuggestionListShowing() is deprecated in SuggestionDisplay interface. Had to cast to default implementation : 

((DefaultSuggestionDisplay) entitySuggestBox.getSuggestionDisplay()).isSuggestionListShowing()